# layout_weight doesn't work on android when I use 0dp layout width

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to lay a map on my application then add a text field and a button on top of it. Below is my xml file. After launch this application, the map is shown on the screen correctly but the text field and button are not there. They are not shown even when I remove the map. What did I miss here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.lenovo.mds.lenovopoc.MainActivity">

<com.amap.api.maps2d.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.70" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button"
    android:layout_weight="0.70"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LinearLayout support android:layout_weight

Comment: RelativeLayout does not support layout_weight ; Use a LinearLayout

Comment: Yup you have to use linear layout if you want to use weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `layout_weight` in RelativeLayout. If you mean to use LinearLayout, the `match_parent` in MapView will occupy all the spaces, so you might assign a `layout_weight` to it.

Comment: I updated the code to use LinearLayout but I got the same result. I want the text and button to be on top of the map. How can I do that in LinearLayout?

Comment: If you want text and button overlay on the map, then use RelativeLayout, no need to assign weights.

Comment: But I want to show the text and button overlay on the map and use the percentage to specify their width. How can I combine these two layouts to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe in this structure:
```
<RelativeLayout>
    <MapView />
    <LinearLayout>
        <EditText />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayouts does not support `layout_weight` for its children. Change to  `LinearLayout` if you want to use it. I don't know if `layout_weight` accepts numbers in `.70` format though.